# Python colunas excel csv

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, number-format, combinações, generators

eu fiz esse gerador de números que ficam salvos em um arquivo csv que eu abro no excel, as combinações são geradas na coluna A mas n quero que apareca na A. 
como faco pra ela aparecer na coluna B e C?

gerar na B, colar na C as mesmas combinações da B

```
   import random

    c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
    c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
    c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))
    lista = []

    print ('---criado por xxx---')

    rc = int (input('Quantas combinacoes?: '))

    def gerar_randomico():
        return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

    def gerar_randomicus():
        return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])

    for i in range(rc):
        lista1 = ('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}\n'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                                  gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                                  gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))

        with open('arquivo.csv','a') as arquivo:
            arquivo.write(str(lista1))
            lista_guardar = lista.append(arquivo)
            print(lista_guardar)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Ao gerar um arquivo multicoluna para o Excel em pt-br, o delimitador deve ser alterado de `,` para `;`.

Pois ao gerar uma lista com os seguintes dados em cada linha:

`("", número_aleatório, número_aleatório)`

O Python gera um arquivo csv com o separador `,`, sendo possível abrir no Google Spreadsheet ou outro tipo de leitor csv. Mas não no Excel em algumas línguas latinas, que utilizam o `;`.

#### Código

```
import random
import csv

c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))
lista = []

print('---criado por xxx---')

rc = int(input('Quantas combinacoes?: '))


def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])


def gerar_randomicus():
    return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])


for i in range(rc):
    lista1 = ('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                                gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                                gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))
    lista.append(("", str(lista1), str(lista1)))


with open('arquivo.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";", dialect="excel", lineterminator = '\n')
    w.writerows(lista)

print(lista)
```

#### Resultado

O resultado para 3 combinações é a seguinte:

```
|   | A |      B      |      C      |
|---|---|-------------|-------------|
| 1 |   | 91962482524 | 91962482524 |
| 2 |   | 91962546353 | 91962546353 |
| 3 |   | 91977396769 | 91977396769 |
```

ou o print da variável lista no Python: `[('', '91962482524', '91962482524'), ('', '91962546353', '91962546353'), ('', '91977396769', '91977396769')]`

Answer (score 0):

O CSV (comma separated value) é um arquivo onde as virgulas (`,`) delimitam as colunas. Se voce quer criar um arquivo com a primeira coluna em branco, voce deve colocar uma virgula no primeiro char da string que sera gravada. Algo como:

```
lista1 = (',{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}\n'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                              gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                              gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))
```

Comment: n deu certo, isso adicionou um "0,"   na frente de cada numero começado com 91

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a biblioteca `pandas` que ajuda extremamente no trabalho de estruturas tabulares você pode simplesmente adicionar uma coluna vazia e depois salvar o arquivo na extensão que desejar.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))
lista = []

print ('---criado por xxx---')

rc = int(input('Quantas combinacoes?: '))

def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

def gerar_randomicus():
    return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))], columns=['B']) for i in range(rc)], ignore_index=True)

df['C'] = df['B']

df.insert(0, 'A', np.nan)

df.to_csv('arquivo.csv', sep=",", header=None, index=None)
```

`df = pd.DataFrame()` cria uma estrutura de dados chamada [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) inicialmente vazia

`df = pd.concat()` é um metodo que entra para simplificar o `lista.append()` que você havia feito. Com ele, você consegue concatenar de [forma nativa e performática](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) os dados desejados, ainda baseado no `for i in range(rc)`. Os valores criados no loop serão adicionados à coluna `B`

`df['C'] = df['B']` cria uma coluna chamada `C` com os mesmos valores da coluna `B`

`df.insert(0, 'A', np.nan)` cria uma coluna chamada `A` com valores nulos (vazios)

`df.to_csv('arquivo.csv', sep=",", header=None, index=None)` realiza a [criação do arquivo .csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) de acordo com os parâmetros passados. `'arquivo.csv'` é o nome do arquivo, `sep=","` é o delimitador (como CSV significa *Comma Separated Values*, o [delimitador é a vírgula](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2)) e finalmente, `header=None` e `index=None` diz que o arquivo deverá ser gerado sem a coluna de index e sem a linha de cabeçalho.

Sei que a sua pergunta não era diretamente sobre Pandas, mas tenho certeza que essa ferramenta irá ajudar muito nessa sua solução e em outras de gênero similar.

[Exemplo funcionando aqui](https://repl.it/repls/RegularAgileBraces)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui funcionou dessa forma. Seria isso?

```
import random

c1 = (random.choice([9, 9]))
c2 = (random.choice([1, 1]))
c3 = (random.choice([9, 9, 9]))
lista = []

print ('---criado por xxx---')

rc = int (input('Quantas combinacoes?: '))

def gerar_randomico():
    return random.choice([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

def gerar_randomicus():
    return random.choice([6, 7, 8, 9])

for i in range(rc):
    # AQUI VOCÊ APENAS GERA O NÚMERO (SEM O \n NO FINAL)
    lista1 = ('{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(c1, c2, c3, gerar_randomicus(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                                  gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico(),
                                                  gerar_randomico(), gerar_randomico()))

    with open('arquivo.csv','a') as arquivo:
        # NA HORA DE ESCREVER NO ARQUIVO, VOCÊ COMEÇA COM ";" 
        # PARA DEIXAR A PRIMEIRA COLUNA LIVRE
        arquivo.write(';'+lista1+';'+lista1+'\n')
        lista_guardar = lista.append(arquivo)
        print(lista_guardar)
```