# Como criar um arquivo CSV via Python mantendo o separador decimal no mesmo lugar?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, python-2.7, csv, google-sheets

Eu tenho um script em Python que faz um requisição via API e salva os dados num arquivo CSV. Os dados são armazenados em diferentes listas no Python e devem ser salvos em diferentes colunas no arquivo CSV. As datas das listas estão originalmente em Unicode (eu tentei, também, transformar para `float` e `str` antes de converter para CSV, mas sem sucesso). Se eu abrir o arquivo CSV gerado no Notepad++ (por exemplo) os dados aparecem exatamente como eu quero:

```
01/02/2019 01:00:00;568.5200;608.7472;654.1030
01/02/2019 02:00:00;577.7830;608.2220;653.7230
```

No entanto, se eu abrir com Excel, os dados aparecem assim (em colunas separadas):

```
01/02/2019 01:00:00 5.685.200   6.087.472   6.541.030
01/02/2019 02:00:00 5.777.830   6.082.220   6.537.230
```

Percebam como o separador decimal foi colocado no lugar errado (se eu clicar na célula, o valor inserido é tido como inteiro, ou 5685200, por exemplo).

O engraçado é que, se eu abrir o arquivo csv com o Google Sheets, ele não faz nenhuma separação pelo delimitador (';') e escreve todos os dados em uma só linha.

Eu estou usando `izip` e `writer.writerows` para converter as listas em colunas num arquivo CSV.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

#Um monte de código

with open('Latencia.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerows(izip(dates, values_min, values_avg, values_max))
```

Eu preciso mudar minha formatação dos dados para que o Excel ou Google Sheets abram o arquivo CSV da maneira que eu quero?

Comment: Veja se [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356045/75104) te ajuda, pois o Excel em português utiliza o delimitador `;`, já o Notepad++ `,`. O Excel em português utiliza a `,` como separador decimal... Você pode abrir o arquivo csv manualmente pelo Excel e escolher as configurações, delimiters, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu maior problema no caso é o `Excel` e não tem nada a ver com o Python - ele está assumindo que a "localidade" (localization) do seu  CSV é em "português do Brasil",e, nessa localidade, o "." é o separador de milhares - a "," é que seria o serparador de casas decimais.

Se na importação no Excel você tiver como explícitar que o arquivo está usando o "locality" "EN-US", o seu problema some.

Se preferir não mexer no Excel no momento da importação, e tendo em mente que seu arquivo só vai funcionar para Excel no Brasil, e vai ter que ser configurado manualmente tanto para importação em outros softwares, quanto para importação no próprio Excel em uma máquina em que a lingua e localização padrão não sejam português do Brasil você pode optar por gravar os números com "," no lugar do ".", fazendo a conversão a partir do Python.

Para isso, basta, ao gravar, passar a sua sequência de números por um gerador simples que faça a conversão. A conversão poderia ser simplesmente:
garantir que o número seja uma string, e um replace de "," por "." - mas isso é pouco elegante - o ideal seria usar a formatação de localização - principalmente se seu script for parte de um sistema grande (que pode ser usado por setores da sua empresa no exterior, ou que vá ser publicado como código aberto, por exemplo).

A lógica do gerador em si é bem simples - uma função que recebe a sequência de números, e para cada número faz o `yield` da forma transformada

```
import csv
import locale
from itertools import izip


#Um monte de código


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "pt_BR.utf-8")

def format(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        yield locale.format_string("%f", float(number))

with open('Latencia.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerows(izip(dates, format(values_min), format(values_avg), format(values_max)))


# Sem se preocupar com a fazer "certo" a parte de localização, a função poderia ser:

def format(numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        yield str(number).replace(".", ",")
```

-Seria possível em ve de usar um generator, fazer uma função simples, para converter um único número, e usar a função `map` - mas isso envolveria escrever três vezes na chamada ao `write` algo como `map(format, values_min)` em vez de `format(values_min`) - fica mais verboso.

(se for usar Python 3 - (por favor, faça isso), tire o "b" no modo de abertura do arquivo, o "i" do "izip"). Por coincidência, o uso do format_string do locale fica o mesmo no código acima.)

## Por fim

Você pode perceber que talvez CSV não seja a melhor forma de transpor seus dados de um lado pro outro - um formato mais determinístico, que não dependa das configurações individuais do software que vai ler os dados pode ser mais apropriado. Python permite que você crie arquivos `.xlsx` diretamente de forma quase tão simples quanto criar um `.csv`, bastando importar a biblioteca correta. Por exemplo, aqui eu instalei o módulo com `pip install openpyxl` - leva menos de 15 segundos - e em seguida, digitei essa sequência no terminal interativo:

```
import openpyxl
import datetime
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
row1 = ["nome1", datetime.date.today(), 1232434.12345, 1234567.8901, 123456.98765]
for i in range(5): sheet.append(row1)
wb.save("teste.xlsx")
```

Pronto - nenhuma conversão necessária - os dados apareceram como deveriam no programa de planilha (no caso, o LibreOffice): números sendo números, datas sendo datas, texto sendo texto! 
E seria fácil criar outras páginas (sheets) na planilha, além de outros controles.

Claro que para ter versões funcionais de bibliotecas desse tipo, repito, é importante você estar numa versão atualizada do Python. 2.7 é uma versão antiga da linguagem, que foi lançada há 10 anos atrás e está no fim do fim de sua vida útil.